# react-select async doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

```
const formatData = ((els) => {
  console.log("ELS : ", els.data); /* Got Undefined */
  return _.each(els, (el) => ({
    label: el.first_name,
    value: el.id,
  }));
});


const fetchOptions = ((input, callback) => {
  return fetch("http://reqres.in/api/users")
    .then((res) => {
      callback(null,
        {
          options: formatData(res.json())
        }
      )
    }).then((json) => {
      return {options: json};
    });
});
```

Based to this [documentation](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#async-options-with-promises), I'm trying to get data and set it to match the format required by `loadOptions` property of `<Select.Async ... />`. As I mentioned above, I got `Undefined` for els.data. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.json()` is asynchronous. It returns a Promise, so handle in the next `then`.

```
const fetchOptions = ((input, callback) => {
  return fetch("http://reqres.in/api/users")
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    }).then((json) => {
      // formatData(json);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please I wanna pass param (custom url) to fetchOptions. Do you know how can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can you do `const fetchOptions = ((input, callback, url) => { ... }`

Comment: Thanks Rick for your reply. I just add bind like : `fetchOptions.bind(url)` in my Select tag to resolve it.